# Google Pay TypeScript definitions

Tags: typescript, google-pay

I have been looking at the new Google Pay API for the web and I want to implement it in a website.

I was following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial), but my script is in TypeScript.

Does anyone know if any TypeScript definitions exist for the new Google Pay for the web API?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is [@types/googlepay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlepay) as part of the [DefinitelyTyped](https://definitelytyped.org/) project.

Assuming you use npm:

```
npm i -D @types/googlepay
```